# How to display a component of my library in my application

Tags: angular, components

I can’t do this. In the library named 'polaris-common', I created the 'AvSearchComponent' component

I did that in app.module.ts of the library:

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
import { PolarisCommonComponent } from './polaris-common.component';
import { AvRechercheComponent } from './av-recherche/av-recherche.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PolarisCommonComponent,
    AvRechercheComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ]
  exports: [
    PolarisCommonComponent,
    AvRechercheComponent
  ]
})
export class PolarisCommonModule { }
```

in the app.module.ts app I did that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

 // module library
import { PolarisCommonModule } from 'polaris-common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    // module library
    PolarisCommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I would like to do something like that in the app.html of the app to display the compo of the library

```
<app-av-recherche><app-av-recherche>
```

Thank you very much

Edit :
[image]

Comment: Can you please share project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this in your app.html but rather in your first bootstraped component which is your `AppComponent` (see the `bootstrap` property of your `NgModule` annotation in your `AppModule`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can yout ell me more, please ?

Comment: When Angular starts, it will bootstrap your first module specified in your main.ts file (AppModule by default). This module must have a first component to render when the app start (the one mentionned in the bootstrap section of this module). This component will be the root component which will define the Angular scope. Every other components must be in this scope (you can see this component as the root of your components' tree, everything outside is ignored as it is out of scope).

Comment: I try tomodify main.ts file like that :
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(PolarisCommonModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
But it doesn't work

Comment: I found my error 
It's because of this import import { PolarisCommonModule } from 'polaris-common';